# How to extract word frequency from document-term matrix?

Tags: python, dictionary, text-mining

I am doing LDA analysis with Python. And I used the following code to create a document-term matrix

```
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in texts].
```

Is there any easy ways to count the word frequency over the whole corpus. Since I do have the dictionary which is a term-id list, I think I can match the word frequency with term-id.

Comment: i haven't used  this much - but is there an issue with using merge_with() or add_documents() ? https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/dictionary.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `nltk` in order to count word frequency in string `texts`

```
from nltk import FreqDist
import nltk
texts = 'hi there hello there'
words = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(texts)
fdist = FreqDist(words)
```

`fdist` will give you word frequency of given string `texts`.

However, you have a list of text. One way to count frequency is to use `CountVectorizer` from `scikit-learn` for list of strings.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
texts = ['hi there', 'hello there', 'hello here you are']
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(texts)
freq = np.ravel(X.sum(axis=0)) # sum each columns to get total counts for each word
```

this `freq` will correspond to value in dictionary `vectorizer.vocabulary_`

```
import operator
# get vocabulary keys, sorted by value
vocab = [v[0] for v in sorted(vectorizer.vocabulary_.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))]
fdist = dict(zip(vocab, freq)) # return same format as nltk
```

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is my texts is not just one document. It appears to be a list, I have texts[1], texts[2]....

Comment: @AegeanT.Wu, I updated an answer in case you have list of texts

Comment: vocab is sorted, but freq isn't, is this still ok?

Comment: @learn2day, yeah it's okay. I only sort vocabulary output from scikit learn so that it's aligned with `freq` array. You can sort output `fdist` dictionary again by its value in order to sort by frequency.

Comment: you can sort by value using `OrderedDict` i.e.  `OrderedDict(sorted(fdist.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)))`