# Python CountVectorizer: presence of term in documents

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lda, countvectorizer

I am doing LDA analysis with Python.
Is there an out of the box way of getting how many texts of my corpus (which is a list of text strings) a word (Edit: a term of n words) is present?

The answer here by @titipata gives the word frequency: [How to extract word frequency from document-term matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37866450/how-to-extract-word-frequency-from-document-term-matrix)

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
texts = ['hey you', 'you ah ah ah']
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(texts)
freq = np.ravel(X.sum(axis=0))

import operator
# get vocabulary keys, sorted by value
vocab = [v[0] for v in sorted(vectorizer.vocabulary_.items(),     key=operator.itemgetter(1))]
fdist = dict(zip(vocab, freq)) # return same format as nltk
```

The word frequency is here:

```
fdist
{u'ah': 3, u'you': 2, u'hey': 1}
```

but I want

```
presence
{u'ah': 1, u'you': 2, u'hey': 1}
```

Edit: this should also work for terms of N-words, which you can define

I can calculate what I want as below, but is there a faster way from CountVectorizer?

```
presence={}
for w in vocab:
    pres=0
    for t in texts:
        pres+=w in set(t.split())
    presence[w]=pres
```

Edit: what I just wrote for presence does not work for terms of N words. This works but is slow:

```
counter = Counter()
for t in texts:
    for term in vectorizer.get_feature_names():
        counter.update({term: term in t})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your corpus is not too large, this should work nicely and quite fast. Also, it relies on python in-builts. See the documentation for [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections).

```
from collections import Counter

corpus = ['hey you', 'you ah ah ah']
sents = []

for sent in corpus:
    sents.extend(list(set(sent.split())))   # Use set et to ensure single count

Counter(sents)
```

Returns:

```
Counter({'ah': 1, 'hey': 1, 'you': 2})
```

Comment: Thank you. I just edited my question because while writing it I forgot I needed to do this for terms of N words, not only for words. For this reason I have to use vectorizer.get_feature_names() and .split() is not helpful

Comment: I could spend some time solving this, but someone already did, luckily: https://gist.github.com/benhoyt/dfafeab26d7c02a52ed17b6229f0cb52 Check this, it seems to do exactly what you need.